# SQL Server data display

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to display a date column in a particular format in SQL Server and need some help with that.

Current display `2013-04-04 15:45:38.497`, required display `20130404154538`

With the below function

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(), 112)
```

I can get `20130404`

Similar thing can be achieved in oracle by

```
TO_CHAR(date_field,'yyyymmddhh24mmss')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about concatenating the result of `112` and `108` and replacing `:` with empty string?

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),dateField, 112) + 
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),dateField, 108), ':', '')
FROM TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f715/3)

which is the same with

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),dateField, 112) + 
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),dateField, 108), ':', '')
FROM TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f715/4)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you could use:

```
    SELECT Format(dateField, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss');
```

Comment: sorry using SQL Server 2008